# How to select multiple anchor points that have a lot of things in between

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I would like to select multiple anchor points but there are a lot of other anchor points between them. This mean that I can't just draw a selection rectangle cause I would select a lot of unwanted anchor points. One way I found to do it is to use lasso tool then press A but this is extremly unconvenient...

It's a scandal that you can't just press A and add anchor to your selection using the **ctrl** key, is there another way to select multiple anchor points than the lasso tool ?

Comment: The Direct Selection Tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You can press the Shift key to add anchor points to your existing selection. This way, you can draw a selection triangle around a few anchor points, and while pressing Shift, drawing more triangles here and there until you've selected all the anchor points you want to select. You can also add individual anchor points by Shift-clicking them, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the lasso tool (shortcut <kbd>Q</kbd>) and draw a freeform selection